# Google Pie Chart is not drawing

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization

Can someone tell me why this is not drawing?

It is drawing perfectly fine when I have 3 slices. But when I add a fourth slice it doesn't draw anymore.

**Code:**

```
function pieChart() {



            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'Placement');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Amount');
            data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});
            data.addRows([
                <?php  
                echo "['1st Place', $first_total, '1st place Received: $first_total times'],";
                echo "['2nd Place', $second_total, '2nd place Received: $second_total times'],";
                echo "['3rd Place', $third_total, '3rd place Received: $third_total times']";

//WHEN I ADD THIS BOTTOM LINE THE CHART NO LONGER DRAWS
                echo "['4th Place', $fourth_total, '4th place Received: $fourth_total times']";

                ?>
            ]);

            var options = {
                tooltip: {isHtml: true},
               // 'title':'Number of times Dancer Placed in top 3 ranks',
                focusTarget: 'category',
                'legend': { position: 'bottom' },
                //'slices': {0: {color: '#D4AF37'}, 1:{color: '#C0C0C0'}, 2:{color: '#CD7F32'}}
            };


            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('pie_chart'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
```

**EDIT**

I did try this code without using php and hardcoding values instead. The result is the same, it will draw with the first 3 slices, but when I add a fourth slice it doesn't draw anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need a comma after the array in the third line...

```
echo "['3rd Place', $third_total, '3rd place Received: $third_total times'],"; // <-- add comma after array
```

Comment: Thank you! I completely missed that! It won't let me accept the answer for another 10 minutes. I will accept your answer at that time. Thank you!